# Apache IoTDB Session method `executeQueryStatement` return no result while CLI works correctly

Tags: database, apache-iotdb, iotdb

Has anyone used Apache IoTDB Session client `executeQueryStatement(String sql)`? It seems only the column names returned when I issued, the result set does not appear.

I am sure that my database and the statement are correctly established since I can query it smoothly with CLI statements.

Using version 1.2.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the java session documents in github of Apache IoTDB, and there should be an example of how to get the result sets of the time series. The link is: [SessionExample.java](https://github.com/apache/iotdb/blob/master/example/session/src/main/java/org/apache/iotdb/SessionExample.java)